# Set correct typing of React Redux' dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Having code like below (not actual working code, just to give you an idea):

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const dispatch = useDispatch()

interface IProp {
  prop: number
}

const [data, setData] = useState<number[]>([])

async ({ prop }: IProp) => {
  const data = await dispatch<any>(
    fetchData({
      prop
    })
  )

  setData(data)
}
```

fetchData typings

```
fetchData({ prop }: IProp): (dispatch, getState) => Promise<number[]>
```

How do I set the type of `dispatch` which will eventually return an array of numbers? `Any` is a temp workaround

EDIT:

`fetchData` is actually an action. I won't get into details here but let's assume it looks like this:

```
export const fetchData = ({
  prop
}) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  // do something store-related like dispatching other actions or getting values from store
  // get `extra`

  const { data } = await actualFetch({
    prop,
    extra
  })

  return data
}
```

Comment: dispatch is for sending action not for making effects. Why You are doing dispatch at all. Just use fetchData , and you should do that inside useEffect, if you want to dispatch also some action do it but after fetching

Comment: @MaciejSikora `fetchData` is actually an Action - I admit naming it this way is unfortunate. Please see my latest edit

Comment: @user0101, Do you use something like redux-thunk? If so, that should be clear in your question and tags. Redux does not support dispatching async functions natively. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: @geon Yes, I do

Comment: @user0101, https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` just returns the action you pass in as the argument. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.ts#L257

There is no reason to await it, and it is not going to contain the fetched data.

As Maciej Sikora mentioned, you do not need redux for this at all. If you still want to pass the data into redux for some reason, do it after you have fetched and processed it.

```
interface Props {
    prop: number
}

function SomeComponent (props: Props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState<number[]>([]);

    const onClick = async () => {
        const data = await fetchData(props);
        setData(data);
    };

    return <div>
        {data}
        <button onClick={onClick}>Fetch!</button>
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Please see my edit and my reply to the Maciej's comment